# Grails access Config properties in Secured annotation

Tags: grails, configuration

I am trying to access the Config of the grails application via the @Secured annotation of spring security with the aim to externalize the role name later.

Sadly, I wasn't able to get this working. Neither by trying to use deprecated ConfigurationHolder class nor getting reference to grailsApplication object.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder as CH
@Secured([CH.config.grails.app.user])
class MyController { ...}

Config.groovy:
...
grails.app.user = "ROLE_APPNAME_USER"
...
```

Does anyone have an advice how to solve this?

*EDIT*
Came across [Burt's article](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1398) which was informational.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't - annotation element values must be compile-time constants because they're resolved by the compiler and stored as part of the class bytecode.

You may have more luck using one of the other mechanisms to specify security constraints (static rules or Requestmap instances in the database) instead of annotations.

Comment: Didn't know  annotation values have to be compile time constraints. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Thought that Grails is able to migrate the constant into the annotation during compile time by substituting the constant with the String before starting the compilation to byte code.

Comment: @MichaelWölm as in Java, you can use anything that's a _compile-time_ constant, such as a reference to a `static final` constant in a `src/java` class, but not something that can only be resolved at runtime.